# Usage of partition key in Azure CosmosDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Until now I used Linq to SQL to make query to my ComosDb database, which worked fine and I did not have to pass the partition key. However I now have to write a more complex query which search for a product on multiple fields so I decided to write to stored procedure, and here I have to pass the partition key to execute it.

- Why passing the partition key is mandatory in some ways and not in others ?

In my use case, I have a collection containing *products* objects which all have a *supplierId* property which is the partition key, and *catalogId* property which contains an array of all catalogs where the product is available.
In my API, I require the *catalogId* to search for a product but not the supplier as it is redundant. Of course I could retrieve the *supplierId* using the *catalogId* first and then pass it to the method calling Cosmosdb but I don't really like it as it would mean that my application layer should be aware of the way the infrastructure works.

- Do you have some advice on how to manage the dependency on the partition key ? Or maybe I did not model my data layer in the best way according to cosmosdb best practices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq may be able to deduce the partition key if it is sent as a filter predicate (where) which is why you didn't need to specify it. But if you're not passing it, Linq will happily run a fan-out query which, when done at large scale is slow and inefficient and definitely avoided at high request volumes.

Stored procs are scoped to a partition key so require it to be passed.

If you're doing a query here I would not use stored procedures as they only execute on the primary replica so can only access 1/4 of the throughput provisioned. Regular queries using the SDK can access any of the 4 replicas so better utilize throughput. This is especially important for high concurrency queries but no matter what you should aim to be efficient.

So if this indeed a cross partition query and you are not passing supplierId for a query which is executed very frequently you may want to look at your partition strategy and analyze your access patterns to your data to ensure that you are designing a database that will scale and be efficient.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, my understanding of cosmosdb stepped up a bit more. In the end I simplified the objects I was storing in order to make the request using Linq easier to write.